# How can I write this in twig

Tags: php, twig, opencart-3

I have a line of php redirect code and I want to write it in twig, as I am using opencart 3. Can anyone kindly let me know how to do it? The code is as below.

```
<?php $this->redirect($this->url->link('product/category', 'path=2')); ?>
```

Comment: Why do you want to redirect from a template/view file?

Comment: @kerbholz I want to redirect it to a category page from home page. Hence I am trying to add this in common/home.twig file.

Comment: @kerbholz I want to redirect it because I want to show the category page to the customers instead of the home page when they type in the main website URL

Comment: Do it in controller.

Answer (score 0):

here you code looks in twig

```
{% set this.redirect(this.url.link('product/category', 'path=2')) = 'undefined' %}
```

hope this might help you